# A rectangle cut into two pieces, which build a square

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, geometry

A rectangle with side length a and b are in ratio $a : b = (n+1)^2 : n^2$, where n is a
positive integer.

Is it possible to cut each such rectangle into two pieces, which
can be put together to build a square?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer to your question:

> Yes, this is always possible

Proof:

> This solution, shown with $n = 6$, can be applied for all $n$. The rectangle with dimensions $n^2$ by $(n+1)^2$ is divided into $n\times(n+1)$ congruent rectangles with dimensions $n$ by $n+1$ such that there are $n$ rows of height $n$ and $n+1$ columns of width $n+1$. The rectangle is cut into two congruent pieces along a stair-step diagonal. These pieces can be arranged to form a square with edge length $n\times(n+1)$, divided into $n+1$ rows of height $n$ and $n$ columns of width $n+1$.
>  [image: Solution]

Comment: The cut is very hard to make out in your picture. Could you color it stronger? And maybe add a text description of what you are doing for visually impaired users ?

Comment: Your rectangle seems to have side in ratio n:(n=1) - 6 and 7 specifically. The case for n=6 would have sides of lengths 49 and 36, which is not the same shape, and does not enable a simplistic 1x1 "staircase" cut.

Comment: @AdamV if you read the (less than 20 words of) explanation given, you'll notice that the non-square looking small rectangles (that go into the square 6 times horizontally and 7 times vertically) do not actually represent unit squares.

Comment: @Bass it's *not* less than 20 words ;-P

Comment: @Falco Your suggestions have been applied.

Comment: Your updated image with improved labelling makes much more sense now. +1

Comment: Perfect - overall a great answer!

Answer (score 7):

I managed to do it like this:

> Start with a rectangle of size 16 x 9 and cut into two parts as shown below:
>
>  [image: 1]
>
>  Then place the pieces together like this to form a 12 x 12 square:
>
>  [image: 2]

Comment: The question is asking if this is possible for all n.

Comment: @DanielMathias OK I see the "each" in the question now.  Looks like you supplied the correct answer for that.  Now I wonder if other rectangles can be cut/pasted into squares or only these kinds?

Comment: The steps of this staircase are each n x (n+1). That will always work because there will always be n divisions of n into n^2, and n+1 divisions of n+1 into (n+1)^2, enabling the "shift and lift" to equalise them so you end up with sides of (n+1) x n and n x (n=1) which are of course the same.